# Javascript nested objects default fallback options

Tags: javascript, object, merge, nested, default

I have a nested option object in javascript. What is the best way to provide default values for them?

**Custom javascript object read from a json file with ajax:**

```
{
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": null,
        "custom": "hello"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions/markdown",
        "limit": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Default options as fallback if values is not set:**

```
{
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": 5,
        "css": "https://example.com/my/style.css"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions",
        "limit": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected results**

Keep everything from custom object and complete it with default values, `"css"` in this case.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": null,
        "css": "https://example.com/my/style.css",
        "custom": "hello"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions/markdown",
        "limit": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

- The custom object may not include all the nested values. If values are missing default value should apply.
- Null, empty and 0 is accepted values and should not be overwritten by default values.
- Values in the custom object that is missing as default values makes no harm and does not need to be dealt with.

**What I've tried to far**

- Spread operator does not merge nested objects - https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-merge-objects-javascript/
- Object assign does not merge nested objects - [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Can you use a library? `jQuery.extend()` has a `deep` option that will recurse. Lodash has `_.merge()`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't want to do that as I already use this in Vue. But in general, that's good information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by checking the value of the object, if an object and check the nested objects or assign the value if the key does not exist.

```js
function update(object, fallback) {
    Object
        .entries(fallback)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                update(object[k] = object[k] || (Array.isArray(v) ? [] : {}), v);
            } else if (!(k in object)) {
                object[k] = v;
            }
        });
}

var object = { fields: { markdown: { preview: { delay: null, custom: "hello" }, revisions: { path: "revisions/markdown", limit: 5 } } } },
    fallback = { fields: { markdown: { preview: { delay: 5, css: "https://example.com/my/style.css" }, revisions: { path: "revisions", limit: 10 } } } };

update(object, fallback);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will treat each array element as a property that needs to be defaulted. It should probably treat the entire array as a single value.

Comment: But that raises the question of how to deal with arrays of objects -- should it recurse into the objects and merge them?

Comment: actually i use each key and value instead of directly taking a reference to `fallback`.

Comment: but anyway the question has only primitives and objects, without arrays inside,

Comment: @NinaScholz I've tested the new code in jsfiddle and the array part does not work as expected. Other than that it's great work. https://jsfiddle.net/0c56tqam/1/

Comment: what should happen with the array?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, you are right. I only asked for object merging. I did not think that arrays will be treated differently than other kinds of values. But I will probably use arrays at some point. The hard part seems to be how they should be treated.

Comment: it's up to you to specify some rules.

Comment: @NinaScholz Crap! I read my fiddle the wrong way. It's working as expected. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [default-composer](https://github.com/aralroca/default-composer) library that work with nested objects:

```js
import { defaultComposer, setConfig } from "default-composer";

// Create a custom emptyChecker
setConfig({ isDefaultableValue: (key, value) => value === undefined })

const data = {
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": null,
        "custom": "hello"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions/markdown",
        "limit": 5
      }
    }
  }
}

const fallback = {
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": 5,
        "css": "https://example.com/my/style.css"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions",
        "limit": 10
      }
    }
  }
}

const result = defaultComposer(fallback, data)
console.log(result)
```

And the output:

```js
{
  "fields": {
    "markdown": {
      "preview": {
        "delay": null,
        "css": "https://example.com/my/style.css",
        "custom": "hello"
      },
      "revisions": {
        "path": "revisions/markdown",
        "limit": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```